# Rename a lot of files

Tags: pdf, batch-file, rename

I need to rename a lot of files.

I have 1 zip file containing 270 PDF files, these have bad names like {4E92C2C7-0A9B-4F77-99CC-D1F03B871564}.pdf
I also have one index pdf file with two colums, 1 with name of file, other with a short description.

Example: 
Airol 1 liter (Airol) (Sikkerhetsdatablad) = {4E92C2C7-0A9B-4F77-99CC-D1F03B871564}.pdf

Is it possible to write a program that looks in column 2 and if file is found, rename it to name in column 1.

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: For now I have been doing this manually, but I see a lot of these zip files coming in the future. I have just begun looking into the problem.  How would you sovle this ? :)

Comment: From the FAQ: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.` [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I would write a program in a scripting language like Python that goes through the index file looking for key/value pairs. If the value is in a specific format (like the first five characters are numbers and/or letters) then search for the original file using the value and rename it to the key.

For the example that you gave:
 Airol 1 liter (Airol) (Sikkerhetsdatablad) = {4E92C2C7-0A9B-4F77-99CC-D1F03B871564}.pdf

A simple pseudo-code will be:

```
For each line in index file:
      split the line into KEY & VALUE (split on the '=' sign)
      If first 5 characters of VALUE are all numbers and/or characters:
            search for the file named VALUE
            rename the file named VALUE to KEY
      End If
```

Comment: Thanks, there is no = sign between the two columns. I don’t know how to use python. However I found another solution. I simply converted the pdf to excel. Made a function using =CONCATENATE command. I put value New name in A1 - And old name B1. Added " symbol in D1 and .pdf to E1. Using this code =("ren ";;D1;B1;D1;" ";D1;A1;E1;D1) Copy down to everything, and I ended up with ren "old name" "newname.pdf"  , Copy this result Colum to notepad and save as bat. Worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Extract list of files to list.txt, then

```
for %f in ({*.pdf) do (
    for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %g in ('type list.txt ^| find "%f" ') do (
        if not "%g"=="" ren "%f" "%g.pdf"
    )
)
```

or just in one line

```
for %f in ({*.pdf) do for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %g in ('type list.txt ^| find "%f" ') do if not "%g"=="" ren "%f" "%g.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Test following script from command line:

```
FOR /F "DELIMS== TOKENS=1,*" %i IN (index_file) DO ECHO REN "%j" "%i.pdf"
```

If result seam to be OK, remove `ECHO` and run it again.